@OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition with wildfly : Principal is anonymous
I'm trying to use the java-ee-kickoff-app (https://github.com/javaeekickoff/java-ee-kickoff-app) with openid.
I'm using keycloak 26.0.5 and wildfly 29.0.1.Final (integrated-jaspi is false).
I created my realm with a user (admin@kickoff.example.org) and a client.
Then I set my parameters :
@OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
    clientId = "java-ee-kickoff-app"
    , clientSecret = "Bv2c31PFMU1G2jvtGdsM1ojfH0eeoefv"
    , providerURI = "http://localhost:8180/realms/java-ee-kickoff-app"
    , redirectToOriginalResource = true
        )
@ApplicationScoped
public class KickoffFormAuthenticationMechanism {
}

I removed the original KickoffIdentityStore
I also created a group IdentityStore :
@ApplicationScoped
public class KickoffGroupIdentityStore implements IdentityStore {

    @Inject
    private PersonService personService;

    @Override
    public Set<ValidationType> validationTypes() {
        return EnumSet.of(ValidationType.PROVIDE_GROUPS);
    }
    @Override
    public Set<String> getCallerGroups(CredentialValidationResult validationResult) {
        String name = validationResult.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
        Person person = personService.getByEmail(name);
        return person.getRolesAsStrings();
    }
}

Going to http://localhost:8080/java-ee-kickoff-app/admin/users triggers the keycloak login page. I enter the credential of the admin user.
Unfortunately I get :
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ELY01177: Authorization failed.
    at org.wildfly.security.jakarta.authentication@3.0.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.jaspi.impl.JaspiAuthenticationContext$1.handleOne(JaspiAuthenticationContext.java:261)

When I debug the application, I can see that the groups are found.
Also org.glassfish.soteria.cdi.DefaultIdentityStoreHandler return a nice CredentialValidationResult with the right name and groups.
Problem : securityContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName() is "anonymous".
So why do I get an authentication failure and why is my principal "anonymous" ?

The same war file in payara-6.2024.10 works fine : no anonymous principal and the page http://localhost:8080/java-ee-kickoff-app/admin/users is displayed after login to keycloak

I removed this part from my web.xml :
<login-config>
    <auth-method>OIDC</auth-method>
</login-config>

So don't add auth-method OIDC in you web.xml if you use @OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition
